# Is disabling wake timers supported under Windows XP?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, power-management

Just curious, can someone confirm if disabling/enabling of wake timers is supported by Windows XP/Server 2003? (I'm obviously talking about programmatic support.)

This stuff:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but no, it's no possible. Vista/XP don't have a way of controlling this, apparently.

See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dedb8e92-2abf-4e71-b3ff-14cecd0166ee/what-are-wake-timers-for-with-regards-to-sleep-mode